# How to get CPU usage percent in C++ using the Sigar libraries

Tags: c++, cpu-usage, sigar

I'm trying to get the CPU usage percent in c++ using the SIGAR libraries, i wrote the code below to try to get this information, but something is wrong, i always got a value 0.3... instead of a value between 0% to 100 %. How to get the CPU usage percent with the SIGAR libraries?

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <sigar.h>
extern "C" 
{
#include <sigar_format.h>
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    sigar_cpu_t cpu1;
    sigar_cpu_t cpu2;
    sigar_cpu_perc_t perc;
    sigar_cpu_perc_calculate(&cpu1, &cpu2, &perc);
    qDebug() << perc.combined;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: What cpu usage do you expect to get?

Comment: I want to get all core CPU usage percent like we get in the task manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**:
I am not a `Sigar` expert, it's the first time I hear it mentioned. From what I could figure out from the code, `sigar_cpu_perc_calculate` determines the load based on a difference between two "snapshots" of the cpu, not using two different CPUs.

I was able to have something that looked somewhat accurate using the following:

```
sigar_t *sigar_cpu;
sigar_cpu_t old;
sigar_cpu_t current;

sigar_open(&sigar_cpu);
sigar_cpu_get(sigar_cpu, &old);

sigar_cpu_perc_t perc;

while(1)
{
    sigar_cpu_get(sigar_cpu, &current);
    sigar_cpu_perc_calculate(&old, &current, &perc);

    std::cout << "CPU " << perc.combined * 100 << "%\n";
    old = current;
    Sleep(100);
}

sigar_close(sigar_cpu);
return 0;
```

Comment: I understand what you are truing to achieve, I'm just trying to understand how 0.3 may related to the code running during this particular run - would 0.3 mean 30%, perhaps?

Comment: From what I could gather online, yes, the value you get is [0,1] so to have percentages you will have to multiply by 100

Comment: I think the 0.3... not means the CPU usage percent because i'm running the program after start a AIDA64 CPU benchmark and the task manager shows 100% CPU usage

Comment: Yes but your "benchmark" is not good as you make your call only once at a specific point of execution

Comment: I put the code inside a loop but i'm getting the same value all times, ex. if the first value is 34 it shows 34,34,34... if the first values is 54 it shows 54,54,54... while the task manager and the AIDA64 shows 100% CPU usage, does the sigar need a initialization?

Comment: Perfect, now i can get the percentage of used CPU.

Comment: So i added double x = perc.combined;  if (x != x) {x = 0;} to check if the value is NaN and overwrite it for zero;